# Сравнение указателей на элементы списка

Tags: c, указатели, список, структуры

нужно сравнить в одно ли место указывают два указателя
функция int delete_max(List *l)
нужно взять один список, и не копируя те элементы, которые заключены между ptr_5 и now_p1, записать их в новый список l_af_del.

в основной части в циклах while происходит ошибка, он не может почему то сравнить два указателя

как это решить?
если пробовать

```
(Item*)(p1) != (Item*) (n->ptr_5)
```

то не работает вре равно

p1 раньше определяется как Item*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Item{
    char symb;
    struct Item *next;
}Item;

typedef struct List {
    Item *head;
    Item *tail;
} List;

typedef struct Stack {
    Item *head;
} Stack;

Stack *stack_new() {
    return (Stack *) calloc(1, sizeof(Stack));
}
List *list_new() {
    return (List *)calloc(1, sizeof(List));
}

int stack_push(Stack *stack, char symb) {
    Item *new = (Item *) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!new) {
        return -1;
    }
    new->symb = symb;
    new->next = stack->head;
    stack->head = new;
    return 0;
}

void stack_print(const List *stack) {
    Item *ptr = stack->head;
    while (ptr) {
        printf("%c ", ptr->symb);
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    printf("*\n");
}

int list_push_back(List *list, char symb) {
    Item *ptr = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (!ptr){
        return -1;
    }
    ptr->symb = symb;
    ptr->next = NULL;
    if (!list->head) {
        list->head = ptr;
        list->tail = ptr;
    } else {
        list->tail->next = ptr;
        list->tail = ptr;
    }
    return 18;
}

void stack_delete_one(Stack *stack) {
    Item *ptr = stack->head;
    if(stack->head->next){
     stack->head= stack->head->next;
        free(ptr);}
        else if ((stack->head->next)== NULL){
            stack->head = NULL;
            free(ptr);
        }
}

void queue_delete(List *queue) {
    Item *ptr = queue->head, *ptr_prev;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr_prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(ptr_prev);
    }
    free(queue);
}

void queue_delete1(Stack *queue) {
    Item *ptr = queue->head, *ptr_prev;
    while (ptr) {
        ptr_prev = ptr;
        ptr = ptr->next;
        free(ptr_prev);
    }
    free(queue);
}


void move(Item *p1){
  while( p1->symb && ( ((p1->symb) != ']') && ((p1->symb) != ')')&&  ((p1->symb) != '(') &&  ((p1->symb) != '[') )){
                p1 = p1->next;
                 }
}

int prov(List *l)
{
  Stack *s = stack_new();
  Item *p1 = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
  p1 = l->head;
move(p1);

 if( ((p1->symb) == ']') ||  ((p1->symb) == ')') ){
                    printf("rrrr");
                    return 88;
                 }
while(p1)
{           if ( p1 && ( ((p1->symb) != ']') && ((p1->symb) != ')')&&  ((p1->symb) != '(') &&  ((p1->symb) != '[') )){
                p1 = p1->next;
                 }

               if( ((p1->symb) == '[') ||  ((p1->symb) == '(') )
                 {
                    stack_push(s, p1->symb);stack_print(s);
                    p1 = p1->next;
                 }

                 else if( (p1->symb) == ')')
                    {
                        printf("stack^1");
                            if(s->head && (s->head->symb) == '(')
                            {
                                   stack_delete_one(s);
                                   p1 = p1->next;

                          }else {
                                    printf("wronng1"); return 88;}
                 }
             else if( (p1->symb) == ']')
                {
                    if(s->head && (s->head->symb) == '[')
                    {
                       stack_delete_one(s);
                       p1= p1 -> next;
                   }
                   else {
                        printf("wronngg2"); return 88;}
                }
}
if((s->head) != NULL )
{
    printf("\nERROOOORR\n");
    return 88;
}
queue_delete1(s);
free(p1);
return 55;
}


typedef struct sk{
    int num_open;
    Item * ptr_5;
    Item * now_p1;
}sk;
//вот здесь начинаются проблемы я думаю
 int func_count( Item * p1 ){
  sk *str_sk = (sk*) malloc(sizeof(sk));
 int count_all = 0;
 str_sk->ptr_5 = p1;
 str_sk->num_open = 0;
 while(p1){
    if( ((p1->symb) == '(') || ((p1->symb) == '[') ){
        (str_sk->num_open) ++;
        count_all++;
        p1 = p1->next;
       } else if ( ((p1->symb) == ')') || ((p1->symb) == ']')   ){
       count_all --;
        p1 = p1->next;
       }
       if( count_all == 0 ){
            str_sk->now_p1 = p1;
        return str_sk;
       }
  }
 }

int delete_max(List *l)
{
int flag = 1;

  List *l_af_del = list_new();
   Item *p1_af_del = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
p1_af_del = l_af_del->head;


  Item *p1 = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
  p1 = l->head;
sk* m = (sk*) malloc(sizeof(sk));
sk* n = (sk*) malloc(sizeof(sk));
move(p1);
m->num_open = 0;
n->num_open = 0;

while(p1)
 {   if ( p1 && ( ((p1->symb) != ']') && ((p1->symb) != ')')&&  ((p1->symb) != '(') &&  ((p1->symb) != '[') )){
                p1 = p1->next;
                 }

   else if( ((p1->symb) == '[') || ((p1->symb) == ']')  ){
        if((p1)){
   p1 = p1->next;}
   }


   else if ((p1->symb) == '('){
            if( (flag == 1) && (m->num_open)==0 ){
                m = (sk*)func_count(p1);
                p1 = m->now_p1;
                 printf("\n m->num_open:%d\n", (m->num_open));
                flag = 0;
                } else if ( flag == 0 && (n->num_open)== 0  ){
                    n = (sk*)func_count(p1);
                     p1 = n->now_p1;
                     printf("\n n->num_open:%d\n", (n->num_open));
                    flag = 1;
                    }
                    if( (n->num_open!=0)&&(m->num_open!=0) ){
                        if( (m->num_open) >= (n->num_open) ){
                            n->num_open = 0;
                            flag = 0;
                        } else if( (m->num_open) < (n->num_open) ){
                            m->num_open = 0;
                            flag = 1;
                        }
                    }
        }
    }


    if (m->num_open == 0){//в n макс вложенность
            p1 = l->head;
            
//вот в этот цикл не заходит
            while( (p1) !=  (n->ptr_5) ){
                p1_af_del->symb = p1->symb;
                p1 = p1->next;
                p1_af_del = p1_af_del->next;
         
            }
            p1 = n->now_p1;
            while(p1){
                p1_af_del->symb = p1->symb;
                p1 = p1->next;
                p1_af_del = p1_af_del->next;
                    }
                
    }

    if (n->num_open == 0){
        // //в m макс вложенность
        p1 = l->head;
        
//то же самое
            while(p1 != m->ptr_5 ){
               (p1_af_del->symb) = (p1->symb);
             
                p1 = p1->next;
                p1_af_del = p1_af_del->next;
            }
            p1 = m->now_p1;
            while(p1){
                p1_af_del->symb = p1->symb;
                p1 = p1->next;
                p1_af_del = p1_af_del->next;
                    }
                 stack_print(l_af_del);

    }
}

int main()
{
int flag_pr = 0;
    int count_sk=0;
      char curr_cymb;
      List *l = list_new();
      while ((curr_cymb = getchar()) != '0' )
      {
            {list_push_back(l, curr_cymb);}
      }
      stack_print(l);
 delete_max(l);
  /*
if( (prov(l)) == 55 ){
    printf("\n*\n");
  delete_max(l);
}*/
queue_delete(l);
      return 27;
```

Comment: Думаю, нужно привести чуточку больше кода, что бы его можно было хотя бы в компилятору скормить и получить ту же ошибку

Comment: окей, сейчас добавила

Comment: полное задание:

Для каждой строки, представляющей собой запись некоторой математической формулы, проверить ее корректность с точки зрения соответствия друг другу открывающих и закрывающих круглых и квадратных скобок, а также, в случае корректности ввода, сформировать новую строку, из которой должна быть максимальной исключена подстрока, ограниченная круглыми скобками максимальной вложенности.

Comment: Скомпилировал. Там странно. Функция func_count возвращает по сигнатуре int,  а в return - указатель на структуру.  так далее. нет смысла рассуждать о сравнении указателей, если там проблема в алгоритме

Comment: даже если sk* func_count( Item * p1 ) то проблема остаётся(

Comment: конечно останется. Во первых, это не единственная проблема, а во вторых, нельзя просто так менять тип, что бы просто было подходяще